# How to automate the Re-sizing of servers in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am working in the AWS environment.  I am re-sizing the production environment, changing the instance type.  Until now I was doing this manually.  I go to console, stop the instance, change the instance type, and start the instance again.
That method is good to do a small amount of servers, but now I need to do hundreds of servers.

Can anyone tell me please how I can automate it?

Answer (score 1):

Resizing instances, let alone *hundreds of instances*, is not something you would normally need to do in production. Ideally your instances should be in **Auto Scaling Group** (ASG) and if you need more computing power you either **add more instances** to your ASG, or update the ASG **Launch Configuration** to a bigger instance size and roll over the ASG.

If you want to use cloud *efficiently* you should really learn how to create **stateless, disposable instances** with data stored in a database (RDS) and/or shared filesystem like EFS. Or better yet deploy your apps in **Docker (ECS) or Kubernetes (EKS)** on a fleet of instances.

That way you will never have to worry about resizing existing instances.

BTW if you really really want to batch-resize your existing EC2s you can write a very simple script using **aws cli** - something like `aws ec2 describe-instances / stop-instance / modify-instance / start-instance ...`, etc.

Hope that helps :)